# Improper integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{sx}}{1+e^{x}} dx$

Tags: complex-analysis, improper-integrals

I'm having trouble solving this problem and was hoping someone could show me how it's done?

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{e^{sx}}{1+e^{x}} dx$$ where $0<Re(s)<1$

Comment: What can you work with? Is the residue theorem available?

Comment: Yes it is. Sorry I didn't specify what could be used

Comment: One option: substitute $z = e^x$, and take a keyhole contour. Another option: shift the contour to the line $\operatorname{Im} z = 2\pi$.

Comment: Try a rectangular contour with $\Im z = 0, 2\pi$ as the horizontal boundaries.